I’m not sure why my suggested edit was rejected
I’m not sure why my suggested edit was rejected.
See here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/151052
I change the formatting for the numbers in the question, as an example:

1 Now, you either go with us or stay here

I changed it to


Now, you either go with us or stay here.


And I also changed the spelling of “anwers”, the correct one should be “answers”.
Was my edit really unnecessary? Was it a very minor edit?

IMO, adding the punctuation where it should be used is not "unnecessary." It could have been a "minor" edit, but it changed everything it could be changed. (I would have replaced the question mark with a period in the last sentence too.)

Wow, suspended network-wide until 2124. Not five or ten years but a hundred. I literally can't imagine what "crime" you were found guilty of. And I guess we'll never know.

@user172727 Ahh, I see it's been reduced. It was 2124. There are cases of users who have been "suspended" for 200 years, so 100 years suspension is not that rare.

User172727's account no longer exists. Interesting…
